# Stop Chrome Autocomplete Dropdown Taking Focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to stop the Chrome autocomplete suggestions dropdown taking focus?

I have an input box within an overlay, and the overlay closes if an element outside of the overlay receives focus.

Hence if a user uses autocomplete to fill out this input box, the overlay closes before the overlay can fire an event.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.  [image]

Just to clarify - using `autocomplete: off` will solve my problem.  But I was hoping to keep autocomplete working as a feature, and just remove the focus.

Comment: You can [turn off autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2530/215552)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey, I was looking for that duplicate  :)

Comment: And if the accepted answer doesn't work then check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40791726/754119) which worked for me

Comment: Thanks - I was preferring to keep the autocomplete feature working - hence I was wondering if there was any way to stop it receiving focus.

However, autocomplete off is a good enough solution if this is not possible.

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Answer (score 3):

Look at this...

```html
<input autocomplete="off">
```

Source: [HTML input autocomplete Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp)

Comment: Thanks - this will resolve my problem, though I was hoping to keep autocomplete working as a feature for users.

Answer (score 1):

Simple as this,

```
  <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
```